# Postfix relaying for multiple domains with Amazon SES

Tags: postfix, amazon-ses

I'm a little confused about relaying with Postfix.

I added this line to my /etc/postfix/transport

```
mydomain34.com   smtp:email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

I know this is wrong, but this is what I have tried. I have multiple domains on my server and I'd like to use Amazon SES only for some domains, other domains would work with the local server as always.